# windows guests on ubuntu virtualbox not starting

Tags: boot, virtualbox, 20.10

My windows guests have stopped working on VirtualBox. They only boot up to black screen with the blue window logo and the rotating thing. After a short while the rotation stops and then the window disappears. After the second try, it says "Automatic repair is being prepared" but the same thing happens.

My linux guests still work.

VirtualBox 6.1.16
Windows 10

Comment: How is this related to Ubuntu?

Comment: Have you tried loading a previous snapshot of the Windows machine to see if it's just this snapshot that is corrupted?

Comment: @vidarlo: Virtualbox is dependent from the Ubuntu kernel version (as you regulary have to reinstall the VBoxGuestAdditions every time the kernel has changed.

Comment: @Eagle_Mike: my second windows guest is a clone from the first and doesn't work either.

Comment: But it's your guest that fails to boot. This suggests that it's a problem with the guest OS installation. We generally don't know fault finding tricks for Windows.

Comment: @vidarlo: My second windows guest is a clone that I had kept for backup and that I haven't touched for months. So why wouldn't it boot anymore? The only things changed are Ubuntu and perhaps Virtualbox installed and updated by Ubuntu.

Comment: Do any other VB guests open correctly?

Comment: @Eagle_Mike I have an Ubuntu and an Android guest which run without any problem.

Comment: It appears that your Windows guest is somehow corrupt and if you are cloning it, the second one would also be corrupt. Try going back to a previous snapshot of the guest (prior to whatever corrupted it). Advise if any of the snapshots are unable to boot up. --- You do take snapshots of the guests regularly?

Comment: The clone was produced months ago, and both the original and the clone were working.

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I did a manual update of Ubuntu. When I tried again today to start my Windows guest system, it worked! Which proves that the Windows system was not corrupt, but that there was a problem somewhere with Ubuntu. Unfortunately I don't know how it was corrected.